# Problema para buscar instrucciones e informacion de un modulo para Python que me instale

Tags: python, cmd, pip, librería, modulos

Hace un rato me descargue un paquete de PyPi -https://pypi.org/project/pkg-taking-45-seconds-to-install/0.0.1/#description- para convertir segundos a minutos.

Dentro de mi consola de comando coloco el comando **python**, luego coloco **import** y coloco el nombre del paquete -**pkg-taking-45-seconds-to-install**- (que luego de verificar con **pip list**) esta instalado

Intento importar el paquete para luego colocar el comando -**help(-nombre del paquete-)**- y de esta forma encontrar las instrucciones dadas por el creador del modulo para poder utilizarlo (en la pagina de PYPI no hay ninguna explicación de como utilizar la librería -https://pypi.org/project/pkg-taking-45-seconds-to-install/0.0.1/#description-)

El problema es que cuando intento importar el modulo me sale un error **File "", line 1
import pkg-taking-45-seconds-to-install
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

{[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al no poder importar el modulo en cuestión, no puedo utilizar el metodo help() para determinar como utilizarlo

Soy nuevo en la programacion y no entiendo como actuar en estos casos. Se me ocurren una serie de escenarios posibles:

.Estoy haciendo mal el procedimiento para encontrar las instrucciones de modulo. (No creo que este sea el caso porque intente hacer el mismo procedimiento con el modulo pandas y pude acceder a la informacion de como usarlo)

.El modulo no tiene instrucciones y tengo que buscar otro y ya (si este fuera el caso, no entiendo como el desarroyador en cuestion no fue capaz de dejar instrucciones en ningun lado)

.la ultima opcion es algun escenario que no estoy considerando

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Ese paquete no sirve, si descargas las fuentes aparece como vacío. Si la cuestión es convertir segundos `seg` a minutos es tan fácil como: `minutos = seg//60` y `seg_restantes = seg%60`.

Comment: Por favor, no repitas las preguntas. Siempre puedes editar la pregunta para corregirla o agregar nuevos detalles. Deberías borrar la otra pregunta que has hecho.

Comment: @CandidMoe el problema planteado no es el mismo. Es uno diferente. Empezando por que el modulo instalado es otro.

Comment: @DanteS. El "metaproblema" es el mismo ...

Comment: No creo, pero la verdad no vale la pena discutirlo. Cada uno con su opinión @CandidMoe

Comment: @CandidMoe. La pregunto no es la misma ya que el modulo y el consecuente error del mismo son otros.

Comment: En las últimas 48 horas has presentado al menos 3 preguntas, más otra(s) eliminada(s), y todas giran en torno a problemas con librerías. Eso me sugiere que el problema es más de fondo.

Comment: El problema es que soy nuevo en la programación, estoy usando por primera vez librerías y por eso cada vez que me surge una nueva inquietud, la pregunto. Mis dudas pueden ser de ayuda para futuros nuevos programadores que empiecen a usar librerías y se encuentren con mis mismos problemas.

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema. Las preguntas que hice, son preguntas con diferentes errores y diferentes dudas. Quizá si en vez de criticarme, me ayudaras a resolver el problema, la historia seria otra

Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

El error de sintaxis proviene del hecho de que `import nombre-con-guiones` es imposible. Los nombres de las funciones, los módulos importados, y las variables no pueden (¿o no deberían?) llevar guiones (pues estos se interpretan como signos de resta).

Ahora, un paquete sí se puede llamar `nombre-con-guiones` y ser instalado bajo ese nombre. Ahora bien, el módulo instalado no debería llamarse `nombre-con-guiones`. Si es el caso, debes comunicarte con el desarrollador para que el módulo se llame, por ejemplo, `nombre_con_guiones`. O en su defecto puedes buscar si el módulo ya tiene un nombre válido, de modo que debas cambiar tu código.